# Find all the pairs of complex numbers $\boldsymbol{z}$ and $\boldsymbol{w}$ such

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, complex-numbers

Find all the pairs of complex numbers $\boldsymbol{z}$ and $\boldsymbol{w}$ such that $\boldsymbol{z\cdot w=-8}$ and one of them is the square of the other one.

$(1)$
\begin{split}
 \, w=z^2 \rightarrow z\cdot w=z\cdot z^2=z^3 \rightarrow z^3=-8  & \Rightarrow z=\sqrt[3]{-8}\\
 & 
\end{split}
$(2)$ 
\begin{split}
 \, -8+0i=8 \text{cis} \pi & \Rightarrow z_{n}=\sqrt[3]8 \text{cis} \left(\frac{\pi}{n}+\frac{2k\pi }{n}\right ) ; k=0,1,2\\
 & \Rightarrow z_{1}=\sqrt[3]8 \text{cis} \left(\frac{\pi}{3} \right)=1+i\sqrt{3}\\
& \Rightarrow z_{2}=\sqrt[3]8 \text{cis}\left(\pi \right)=-2 \\
& \Rightarrow z_{3}=\sqrt[3]8 \text{cis} \left(\frac{5\pi}{3} \right)=1-i\sqrt{3}
\end{split}

$(3)$
\begin{split}
 w_{1}&= (z_{1})^2=(1+i\sqrt{3})^2=-2+2i\sqrt3\\
w_{2}&=  (z_{2})^2=(-2)^2=4 \\
w_{3}&=  (z_{3})^2=(1-i\sqrt{3})^2=-2-2i\sqrt{3}
\end{split}

Then the pair of complex numbers are:

$z_{1}= 1+i\sqrt{3} $ and  $w_{1}= -2+2i\sqrt{3} $

$z_{2}= -2 $ and  $w_{2}= 4 $

$z_{3}= 1-i\sqrt{3} $ and  $w_{3}= -2-2i\sqrt{3} $

---

Is correct my work and answer? Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: i don't reelly understand your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is true. Also you need the following case: $z=w^2$, but it's the same work.

Another way:
$$z^3=-8$$ or
$$z^3+8=0$$ or
$$(z+2)(z^2-2z+4)=0$$
and we got
$$z\in\{-2,1+\sqrt3i,1-\sqrt3i\}$$ and
$$w\in\{4,-2+2\sqrt3i,-2-2\sqrt3i\}$$

Comment: Thank you, can you help me with this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446468/prove-if-w-is-4th-root-of-i-then-barw-is-4th-root-of-i

Comment: @Daniel I think the solution of Kenny Lau is true.