# Prove if $w$ is 4th root of $i$ then $\bar{w}$ is 4th root of $-i$

Tags: complex-numbers

$(1)$
\begin{split}
 i=1\text{cis}(\pi/2)
\end{split}

$(2)$

\begin{split}
 w_{1}= &\text{cis} (\pi/8) \\
w_{2}=&\text{cis} (5\pi/8) \\
w_{3}=&\text{cis} (9\pi/8) \\
w_{4}=&\text{cis} (13\pi/8)
\end{split}

$(3)$
\begin{split}
 \bar{w_{1}}= &\text{cis} (15\pi/8) \\
\bar{w_{2}}=&\text{cis} (11\pi/8) \\
\bar{w_{3}}=&\text{cis} (7\pi/8) \\
\bar{w_{4}}=&\text{cis} (3\pi/8)
\end{split}

---

$(4)$
\begin{split}
 -i=1\text{cis}(3\pi/2)
\end{split}
$(5)$

\begin{split}
 w_{1}= &\text{cis} (3\pi/8) \\
w_{2}=&\text{cis} (7\pi/8) \\
w_{3}=&\text{cis} (11\pi/8) \\
w_{4}=&\text{cis} (15\pi/8)
\end{split}

### (3)=(5)

Is there a better way to prove the statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\omega$ is a fourth root of $i$ if and only if $\omega^4=i$, which is true if and only if $\overline{\omega^4}=\overline{i}$, which is if and only if $(\overline\omega)^4=\overline{i}$, or if and only if $(\overline\omega)^4=-i$, if and only if $\overline\omega$ is a fourth root of $-i$.

Comment: The justification for $\overline{\omega^4} = (\overline\omega)^4$ can either be "$p(\overline z) = \overline{p(z)}$ for all polynomial $p$" if you already know it, or $\overline{\omega^4} = \overline{(re^{i\theta})^4} = \overline{r^4 e^{4i\theta}} = r^4 e^{-4i\theta} = (re^{-i\theta})^4 = (\overline\omega)^4$ if you don't.

Comment: I don't  understand why if $w^4=i \Rightarrow \overline{w^4}=\overline{i}$ ?

Comment: @Daniel taking conjugate of both sides is a valid step :P

Comment: and what is the proof? :v

Comment: @Daniel that conjugate is a function that sends the same input to the same output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66242/discussion-between-daniel-and-kenny-lau).